# Duplicates of text in UITextField when inside UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have created a `UITextField` in a `UITableView`. I type the data in and close the keyboard. However when I scroll down and hide the `UITextField` and then scroll back up again, the 'UITextField' data is duplicated as seen below:

Original Load of View:
[image]

Typed in Data: [image]

After hidden textfield and then started editing again:[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if ([indexPath section] == 0) { // Email & Password Section
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Subject";
} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Task";
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
    UITextField *subject = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
    subject.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    subject.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        subject.placeholder = @"Maths";
        subject.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
        subject.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    }
    subject.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    subject.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    subject.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    subject.tag = 0;
    subject.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:subject];
} else {
    UITextView *task = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(102, 0, 185, 40)];
    task.text = @"fasfashfjasfhasfasdjhasgdgasdhjagshjdgashjdgahjsdghjasgasdashgdgjasd";
    task.editable = NO;
    task.scrollEnabled = NO;
    task.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    task.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 62.0/255.0 green: 85.0/255.0 blue:132.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    task.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}



return cell;
```

}

Comment: post your textField delegate methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Richard said, cells are reused (that's what the identifier purpose is), and that's why you test in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for a `nil` value returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.
If a cell already exists (ie. was allocated earlier) and is not displayed anymore, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will use this cell to display the content of the newly appearing cell.

What you are doing is adding your `UITextView` every time your cells are **displayed** and not **created**. So each time a cell is gets scrolled out of the screen and a new cell pops in, you append a new `UITextView` in the cell. You should add subviews only in the `if (cell == nil)` part of your method. As the content of your cells are rather different, I'd recommend using two distinct identifiers.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifierForSection0 = @"Cell0";
    static NSString *CellIdentifierForSection1 = @"Cell1";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [indexPath section] == 0 ? CellIdentifierForSection0 : CellIdentifierForSection1];
    if (cell == nil) {

        if ([indexPath section] == 0) { // Email & Password Section

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierForSection0];
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Subject";

            UITextField *subject = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
            subject.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            subject.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
                subject.placeholder = @"Maths";
                subject.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
                subject.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            }
            subject.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            subject.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            subject.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
            subject.tag = 0;
            subject.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:subject];
        } else {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierForSection1];
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Task";

            UITextView *task = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(102, 0, 185, 40)];
            task.text = @"fasfashfjasfhasfasdjhasgdgasdhjagshjdgashjdgahjsdghjasgasdashgdgjasd";
            task.editable = NO;
            task.scrollEnabled = NO;
            task.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            task.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 62.0/255.0 green: 85.0/255.0 blue:132.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            task.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Note that this code is mainly for example purpose, and could be greatly reducted. Moreover, you should use subclass(es) of `UITableViewCell` like Richard suggested, as it will help organizing your code and make it more reusable.

**BUT** do NOT use `drawRect:` to add subviews. This is unnecessary and will impact performances. `drawRect:` should only be used if you intend to make *real* drawing like with CoreAnimation or CoreGraphics. Adding subview should be done in `initWithFrame:` or `initWithCoder:` depending of your use of Interface Builder or not.

Comment: I'd change to `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [indexPath section] == 0 ? CellIdentifierForSection0 : CellIdentifierForSection1];`

Answer (score 0):

Remember cells get reused, therefore the subviews are added each time it's reused.  If you're going to add subviews to a cell you're best off creating a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and adding the subviews in the `drawRect:` method of that subclass.  That way the modifications are part of the cell and aren't added each time the cell is reused.

Comment: Adding subviews in `drawRect:` is an awfull idea. You should not do that. From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:): `you do not need to override this method if your view just displays a background color or if your view sets its content directly using the underlying layer object`.

Comment: I stand corrected, the code should go in the initializer.  A lot can be done with `UITableVIewCell` prototypes now as well.

Comment: I never said your were wrong. Just pointing out the bad practice in your answer :).